# Selección de Multiples Líneas de diferente largo con Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

estoy intentado seleccionar multiples líneas en sublime text 3 en Windows 10 para ahorrarme tiempo, uso el comando Control+Alt+Down para seleccionar las líneas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y todo va bien hasta la penultima línea, pero, cuando selecciono la ultima línea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso sucede,
Alguien sabe como usar este comando para que solo seleccione el final de las líneas sin que este error suceda o conoce otro comando para seleccionar multiples líneas?

Comment: Con el muticursor ubicado  en las lineas justo como lo muestras, presiona la tecla `end` para llevar los cursores hasta al final de cada línea.

Comment: Lo intente, no funciono, pero encontré una solución, igual gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Otra forma de hacerlo que para mí es más fácil es seleccionar todas las filas que deseas y luego presionar `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `L` eso divide la selección en líneas y si deseas ir al inicio o final de la línea puedes utilizar los botones "Inicio" o "Fin"

[Aquí](https://www.mediasuite.co.nz/blog/sublime-tips-multi-cursor-mastery/) hay un artículo con varios tips.

Comment: Funciono tu opción y es mas rápida, Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré una solución alternativa.
Cuando llego a la línea que se selecciona incorrectamente, simplemente suelto la tecla ALT pero mantengo la tecla CONTROL apretada y con el mouse hago click en el final de la palabra que quiero seleccionar.